# IE10 Clicking thumbnail opens large image in new window instead of replacing featured image

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, shopify

I have a Shopify store which has thumbnails under the featured image when there are color variants for that product. When you click a thumbnail image, it replaces the featured image with a large version of the thumbnail. This works great in the usual Chrome, Firefox, Safari, but it doesn't work in IE10. In IE10 when I click the thumbnail it opens the large version in a new window instead of replacing the image.

Here's my HTML:

```
{% if product.images.size > 1 %}
      <ul id="product-photo-thumbs" class="clearfix grid">
        {% for image in product.images %}
        <li class="product-photo-thumb">
          <a href="{{ image.src | product_img_url: 'grande' }}">
            <img src="{{ image.src | product_img_url: 'small' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" />
          </a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      {% endif %}
```

And here's the javascript:

```
  // Load variant image into feature area
  $('.product-photo-thumb a').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#product-photo-container img').attr('src',url);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Any ideas(other than telling my customers to stop using IE :P)? THANKS!

Comment: The JS isn't properly running in IE, that's why the default click action occurs when clicking on an image. I suggest watching your error console (and set it to not delete itself when the page changes). ...edit... also I just noticed that you are calling `event.preventDefault()` but you're not declaring the `event` argument in your event handler. You can instead use `return false` or just add `event` as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Load variant image into feature area
$('.product-photo-thumb a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#product-photo-container img').attr('src',url);
});
```

I think you need 2 things, a variable, use `e` instead of `event` to avoid keyword collision. Place the `preventDefault` before you actually do stuff.

Comment: If you have a click event handler, you don't need an <a>. Then you don't have to worry about the event propagation.